# Read File and extract to different output

Tags: java, readfile

I have the following data. What I'm trying to do is to separate every reading into different outputs, but it does not work. It only show 'null'. What i expected to work are:

Output:
C.txt
1 1000 1000
2 2000 2000

Output: B.txt
1 2 90.000 2
2 3 180.000 2

Output: D.txt
1 2 100.1 0.038
2 3 200.1 0.038

Data in Input.txt:
C;1;1000;1000
C;2;2000;2000

B;1;2;90.00;2
B;2;3;180.00;2

D;1;2;100.1;0.038
D;2;3;200.1;0.038

```js
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class ReadFile {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader input = null; //read
    PrintWriter outC = null; //write output
    PrintWriter outB = null;
    PrintWriter outD = null;
    try {
      input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\FYP\\Input.txt"));
      outC = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\FYP_Test\\C.txt")));
      outB = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\FYP_Test\\B.txt")));
      outD = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\FYP_Test\\D.txt")));

      String inputData = null;
      int C = 0;
      int B = 0;
      int D = 0;
      while ((inputData = input.readLine()) != null) {
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(inputData, ";");
        String id = tokenizer.nextToken();
        String StnFrom = tokenizer.nextToken();
        String NorthingTo = tokenizer.nextToken();
        String EastingDistBrg = tokenizer.nextToken();
        String StdError = tokenizer.nextToken();

        if (id.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
          C++;
          outC.println(StnFrom + " " + NorthingTo + " " + EastingDistBrg);
        } else if (id.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
          B++;
          outB.println(StnFrom + " " + NorthingTo + " " + EastingDistBrg + " " + StdError);
        } else if (id.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
          D++;
          outB.println(StnFrom + " " + NorthingTo + " " + EastingDistBrg + " " + StdError);
        }
      }
      input.close();
      outC.close();
      outB.close();
      outD.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
      System.out.println(fe.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException iox) {
      System.out.println(iox.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the details on "it does not work", and also what you expected to work.

Comment: Remove all your catch blocks. Don't surround the code with a try block. Add the necessary throws clause to the main method. Then run your code again. You'll get a clear stack trace, showing what the exception is, and where it's thrown. Read it, and draw conclusions. Use your debugger to help understand, line by line, what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tokenizer.nextToken()` will throw `NoSuchElementException` when there are no more tokens in the tokenizer's string.

Your sample input, if provided, will throw "NoSuchElementException" because Data in "Input.txt" for "C" is wrong. In your program, you are calling "nextToken" five times, whereas data for "C" contains only 4 values(C;1;1000;1000).

Below, is improved "Input" data.

```
C;1;1000;1000;1
C;2;2000;2000;1

B;1;2;90.00;2
B;2;3;180.00;2

D;1;2;100.1;0.038
D;2;3;200.1;0.038
```

Also, you need to improve your while loop to read empty line. Currently, it will throw Error.
Consider below while loop:

```
while ((inputData = input.readLine()) != null) {
        if(inputData.length() != 0) {
          StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(inputData, ";");
          String id = tokenizer.nextToken();
          String StnFrom = tokenizer.nextToken();
          String NorthingTo = tokenizer.nextToken();
          String EastingDistBrg = tokenizer.nextToken();
          String StdError = tokenizer.nextToken();

          if (id.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
            C++;
            outC.println(StnFrom + " " + NorthingTo + " " + EastingDistBrg);
          } else if (id.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
            B++;
            outB.println(StnFrom + " " + NorthingTo + " " + EastingDistBrg + " " + StdError);
          } else if (id.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
            D++;
            outD.println(StnFrom + " " + NorthingTo + " " + EastingDistBrg + " " + StdError);
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Welcome @Harith